# How can I create an authentication cookie, but w/o asp.net formsauthentication?

Tags: asp.net, security, cryptography, forms-authentication

Do we know the algorithm that asp.net uses to create the authentication cookie (when using forms authentication?)

Can we basically create our own copy implementation? if so, how?

What does it use to generate the encrypted cookie value, I know it uses whatever you pass into the SetAuthCookie call (which is usually the userID/username).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The forms authentication take uses the membership identifier, a unique value provided by the configured membership provider. It then takes that value, plus any user data set in the ticket turns it into a binary blob, adds an issue date, an expiry date and depending on the configuration either signs it with an HMAC using the machine key, signs and encrypts it with the machine key, or does nothing at all (bad idea!).

It then writes the cookie out as an HTTP only cookie.

Then on each request it loads it in, validates it, uses the membership identifier to lookup the user, and populates the user details on that thread. If sliding ticket expiry is set it will refresh the cookie to have a new expiry date.